# to be able to run the following jquery automatically

Tags: jquery

Has anyone worked with the follwoing jquery plugin? I can shift though the images by clicking the arrows but I like images to auto display one after another. I was curious to see if this is an option to run this slide show as autoplay.

this is the websiste to the plugin:

```
http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/jfancytile_a_jquery_tile_shifting_image_viewer_plugin.html

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jfancytile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Default
        $("#fancytile").jfancytile();

        // With options
        $("#fancytile").jfancytile({
            inEasing: "easeOutBounce", // from jQuery Easing Plugin
            outEasing: "easeInCirc", // from jQuery Easing Plugin
            inSpeed: 2000,
            outSpeed: 3500,
            rowCount: 5,
            columnCount: 10,
            maxTileShift: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation and elaborate on your question?

Comment: Not according to the source code. You'll have to hack this one, yourself (inside the jquery.jfancytile.js plugin code).

Comment: @Asad, I updated the post. I really like this plugin and like to use it. I couldn't find any marks about showing the images autoplay rather than manually clicking the arrows to go to the next image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use small hack:

```
var iID;
clearInterval(iID);
iID = setInterval(
    function() {
        $('.jfancytileForward').trigger('click');    
    }, 
    1500
);
```

Comment: that worked. One more question, how can I pick the Demo 2 - Custom?

Comment: add parent div with id `<div id="tile1">...</div>` and `$('#tile1 .jfancytileForward')`

Comment: I spoke to early. when I put the your hack in "jquery.jfancytile.js" file, I get an error. where do I put this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try `setInterval` to trigger a click on the arrow:

```
// trigger a click on the 'next' arrow every 5 seconds
// use clearInterval(nextInterval) to remove timer
var nextInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $('#arrowSelectorHere').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

Very hacky, but should work...?